# magento 1.9: How should I use Magento's API

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I am implementing a program that communicates with `magento 1.9` using `JavaScript`. We only need to obtain the `product information on the system` and display it. Does not operate the database (for example: add and delete),

what should I do? Appreciated your help, Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Magento describes the process on using the built in APIs pretty well, really. See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html.

More specifically, take a look at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html which has a full PHP example at the header *"Retrieve the list of products for Customer user with OAuth authentication"*. I realize you're using javascript but this should make it clear enough I think.

Forgot to add this one: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/response_formats.html explains how to get JSON as a response rather than XML.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find the answer acceptable, please accept it so that the question wont remain marked as unanswered :)